# Nginx serving a directory as an alias

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use ResourceSpace as an alias on Nginx. The page scripts load well but static files do not load. Access to subdirectories gives an error of `undefined index`

eximmanger loads with all scripts plus static files while resourcespace fails to load static files, loading only the scripts

This is my config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com www.myserver.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/myserver.access_log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myserver.error_log info;

    location /resourcespace { 
        alias /var/www/html/ResourceSpace/;

     }


    location /eximmanager { 
        alias /var/www/html/exim4u/exim4u/;

     }

    location /100/ { 
           rewrite ^ http://100.myserver permanent;

     }




   location ~ ^/eximmanger/(.+\.*)$ {
      alias /var/www/html/exim4u/exim4u/$1;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;

      # From fastcgi_params
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      /var/www/html/exim4u/exim4u; # <-- Changed
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
    }


   location ~ ^/resourcespace/(.+\.*)$ {
      alias /var/www/html/ResourceSpace/$1;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;

      # From fastcgi_params
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      /var/www/html/ResourceSpace; # <-- Changed
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
    }


    root /var/www/html/myserver;
    index index.php;
    # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }

    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
    # deny running scripts inside writable directories
    location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
            return 403;
            error_page 403 /403_error.html;
    }



    location ~ .*.php$ {
        #include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


    }

    # caching of files 
    location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
            expires 1y;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
            expires 14d;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the problem was not related to nginx at all , but to the ResourceSpace `$baseurl` directive. In the directive I had mixed up `$baseurl = 'http://resourcespace.myserver.com';` and `$baseurl = 'http://myserver.com/resourcespace';` . So watch out for that if you having similar problems.